# Alcohol discounts in VA

Tags: united-states, alcohol, virginia

It has come to my attention that in some states such as Virginia, you may not be able to offer discounts on alcohol. Looking at the FAQ of a popular app that offers discounts at restaurants in VA I see that they say VA and PA (USA) don't allow you to offer discounts on alcohol:
http://www.spotluck.com/faq/   (#12)

Looking at the VA ABC laws, the closest I could find is "happy hour laws", which seem to just govern the way you advertise, and that you can't do BOGO alcohol:
https://www.abc.virginia.gov/licenses/retail-resources/happy-hour

Are there any resources that elaborate on how/why you can or can't offer discounts, such as in the way the Spotluck app claims they can't offer discounts off alcohol orders?